# Erro 503 no PHP

Tags: php

Estou com um script que faz a introdução de várias informações no banco de dados e salva alguns arquivos no servidor através de URL, porém o PHP encerra o processo antes da finalização com o erro 503.

Já tentei (acredito eu) que todas as formas de adiar isso pelo .ini e por comandos na própria pagina.

Alguém mais tem alguma ideia do que fazer ?

Segue código aplicado na pagina para entender a execução:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
```

As mesmas alterações foram feiras na php.ini do servidor.

Comment: Quais arquivos são esses ? São pesados ? Tamanho.

Comment: Esses dois fatores que você citou, acesso a disco e a banco de dados: elimine um deles como teste, o gargalo deve estar aí. Eu apostaria no banco de dados.

Comment: Tem acesso aos *logs* do `php` ou servidor web? Caso positivo, o que é escrito no `log`?

Comment: São Fotos, Acredito que Sejam Pesados.

Comment: bfvaretto, o cadastro no banco ocorre tranquilamente sozinho, o problema acredito ser no salvar as fotos.

Comment: Valdeir Por, não tenho os logs